# Redirect Rule in IIS

Tags: iis, redirect

I am want to redirect a url to another url by using IIS redirect. But i need to know how can i achieve this by using IIS redirect and also i need regular expression which redirect a specific URL to another url.

this is the Url which user will hit.

http://myurl.com/blog/social-media-page/

now i need to redirect above url to this url

http://blog.myurl.com/social-media-page/

how can i achieve this by using IIS redirect. I need to do this immediately.

Comment: Try google it out. This was described 10^6 times.

Comment: yes it does but in my case i need regex which i am not able to find in google

Comment: i am new in regex that's why i am having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

For IIS 7+ update web.config of **myurl.com** to have following redirect

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    ..
</configSections>
<location path="social-media-page">
     <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://blog.myurl.com/social-media-page/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" childOnly="true" />
     </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I tested it and it works fine.  All whats come to myurl.com/social-media-page is redirected (permanent redirect) to blog.myurl.com/social-media-page.